# How to Send Email verification using angularjs and php?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I created registration form and corresponding controller and backend php code.
The registered data is storing correctly . But i am not reciving mail in my email id. Please help me with this..

My html Code

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 well " style="margin-top:1em; background-color:black; ">

  <h4 style="color:white; text-align:center;"> <strong> FILL UP REGISTRAION FORM  </strong> </h4>

</div>


<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 well" style="margin-bottom:10em;">

  <form name="register" ng-app="TempleWebApp" ng-controller="RegisterCtrl" ng-submit="SignUp(register.$valid)" novalidate>

    <!-- First Name -->
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : register.fname.$invalid && (register.fname.$dirty || submitted)}">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fname" ng-model="fname" placeholder="First Name" ng-required="true">
      <span class="help-block" ng-show="register.fname.$invalid && register.fname.$error.required && (register.fname.$dirty || submitted)">
              First Name is required.</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Last Name -->
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : register.lname.$invalid && (register.lname.$dirty || submitted)}">
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lname" ng-model="lname" placeholder="Last Name" ng-required="true">
      <span class="help-block" ng-show="register.lname.$invalid && register.lname.$error.required && (register.lname.$dirty || submitted)">
             Last Name is required.</span>
    </div>

    <!-- City -->
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : register.city.$invalid && (register.city.$dirty || submitted)}">
      <label>City</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" ng-model="city" placeholder="City" ng-required="true">
      <span class="help-block" ng-show="register.city.$invalid && register.city.$error.required && (register.city.$dirty || submitted)">
             City is required.</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Gender -->
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : register.gender.$invalid && (register.gender.$dirty || submitted)}">
      <label>Gender</label> <br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" ng-model="gender" value="male" ng-required="true"> Male
      <input type="radio" name="gender" ng-model="gender" value="female" ng-required="true" style="margin-left:5em;"> Female
      <span class="help-block" ng-show="register.gender.$invalid && register.gender.$error.required && (register.gender.$dirty || submitted)">
             Gender is required.</span>
    </div>


    <!-- Email -->
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : register.email.$invalid && (register.email.$dirty || submitted)}">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" ng-model="useremail" placeholder="Email" ng-pattern="/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/" ng-required="true">
      <span class="help-block" ng-show="register.email.$invalid && register.email.$error.required && (register.email.$dirty || submitted)">
              Email is required.</span>
      <span class="help-block" ng-show="register.email.$error.pattern">
            Enter Valid  Email .</span>
    </div>


    <!-- Password -->
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : register.password.$invalid && (register.password.$dirty || submitted)}">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" ng-model="userpassword" placeholder="Password" ng-required="true">
      <span class="help-block" ng-show="register.password.$invalid && register.password.$error.required && (register.password.$dirty || submitted)">
              Password is required.</span>
    </div>

    <!-- CONFIRM PASSWORD -->
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : register.confirmPassword.$invalid && (register.confirmPassword.$dirty || submitted)}">
      <label>Confirm Password</label>
      <input type="Password" name="confirmPassword" class="form-control" ng-model="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Your Password" ng-compare="password" ng-required="true">
      <p ng-show="register.confirmPassword.$error.required && (register.confirmPassword.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">confirm password is required.</p>
      <p ng-show="register.confirmPassword.$error.compare  && (register.confirmPassword.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Confirm password doesnot match.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 well " ng-repeat="error in errors" style="background-color:red; margin-top:0.5em;"> {{ error}} </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 well" ng-repeat="msg in msgs" style="margin-top:0.5em;">
      <h5 style="color:green;">{{ msg}} </h5>
    </div>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-lg-12">
      <span ng-show="searchButtonText == 'REGISTERING'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spinning"></i></span>
                  {{ searchButtonText }}
    </button>


  </form>
</div>
```

My controller

app.controller('RegisterCtrl', function ($scope,$location, $http,$timeout) {

```
          $scope.gender = '';


            $scope.errors = [];
            $scope.msgs = [];
            $scope.searchButtonText = "REGISTER DETAILS";
            $scope.test = "false";


           $scope.SignUp = function(isValid) {

               // Set the 'submitted' flag to true
              $scope.submitted = true; 
               $scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); // remove all error messages
                $scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length);



              if (isValid) {  

               $http.post('php/register.php', 
                            { 'fname': $scope.fname, 
                              'lname': $scope.lname, 
                              'city': $scope.city, 
                              'gender': $scope.gender, 
                              'pswd' : $scope.userpassword, 
                              'email': $scope.useremail
                            })
                    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        if (data.msg != '')
                        {
                        $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
                        $scope.test = "true";
                        $scope.searchButtonText = "REGISTERING";
                        //var goTopayment = function() { $scope.searchButtonText = "REGISTER DETAILS"; $location.path('/login'); };
                        // $timeout(goTopayment, 3000);
                        }
                      else
                      {
                        $scope.errors.push(data.error);
                       }
                     })
                  .error(function(data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs or server returns response with an error status.

                    $scope.errors.push(status);
                    });
            } // closing bracket for IF(isvalid)

        } // closing bracket for $scope.SIGNUP = function
```

}); // closing bracket for register

My php Code is

```html
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->fname);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->lname);
$city = mysql_real_escape_string($data->city);
$gender = mysql_real_escape_string($data->gender);
$upswd = mysql_real_escape_string($data->pswd);
$uemail = mysql_real_escape_string($data->email);


$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('registraion', $con);

$qry_em = 'select count(*) as cnt from users where Email ="' . $uemail . '"';
$qry_res = mysql_query($qry_em);
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_res);



if($res['cnt']==0){
$qry = 'INSERT INTO users (Firstname,Lastname,City,Gender,Password,Email) values 
               ("' . $fname . '","' . $lname . '","' . $city . '","' . $gender . '","' . $upswd . '","' . $uemail . '")';
      
$qry_res1 = mysql_query($qry);

     if (!$qry_res1) {
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
  } else {
   return mysql_insert_id();
  }
 
 
 $current_id = mysql_insert_id(); //last insert id      

 
   if(!empty($current_id)) {
    $actual_link = "http://localhost/angular/php/"."activate.php?uid=" . $current_id;
    
    $EmailTo =  $uemail ;
    $Subject = "User Registration Activation Email";
    $Content = "Click this link to activate your account. <a href='" . $actual_link . "'>" . $actual_link . "</a>";
    $MailHeaders = "From: Admin\r\n";
    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Content, $MailHeaders);
    
    
    if($success ) {
     
           $arr = array('msg' => "You have registered and the activation mail is sent to your email. Click the activation link to activate you account.", 'error' => '');
                    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
                    print_r($jsn);
     
      }
    } 
 
}


else
{
     $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'User Already exists with same email');
    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
    print_r($jsn);
}
?>
```

Comment: Sry updated now...

Comment: Do you receive an error from `mail` function?

Comment: No mail function doesn't returned any error.

Comment: The you may be blocked by the mail server. Check you `/var/log/maillog` on the server to see if there are any delivery errors.

Comment: Are you testing this on a local machine? If so, the mail never gets sent as your machine cannot send out emails. You must have your code hosted on a server with SMTP available to send out mails.

Comment: Yes i am running it local. But we can use test mail sever tool for testing it locally right?

Comment: Because I am using same tool for my contact form .

Comment: In my contact form i am adding email id of mine as hard code. it is sending mail to that email id locally.. but not here as dynamically getting mail id from currently registering users.. may be anything fault in getting last insert id or in $Emailto  value ...???

Comment: Even if i hard code here  for $Emailto value mail is sending . but  if use this dynamically getting value then no mail is sending.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it. The problem was finding last inserted id value for $current_id variable.Since i was not getting correct value for this variable, value for $Emailto variable is not assigned with email id. So  I changed php code to following way.

```js
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->fname);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->lname);
$city = mysql_real_escape_string($data->city);
$gender = mysql_real_escape_string($data->gender);
$upswd = mysql_real_escape_string($data->pswd);
$uemail = mysql_real_escape_string($data->email);


$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('registraion', $con);

$qry_em = 'select count(*) as cnt from users where Email ="' . $uemail . '"';
$qry_res = mysql_query($qry_em);
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_res);



if($res['cnt']==0){
$qry = 'INSERT INTO users (Firstname,Lastname,City,Gender,Password,Email) values 
               ("' . $fname . '","' . $lname . '","' . $city . '","' . $gender . '","' . $upswd . '","' . $uemail . '")';
      
$qry_res1 = mysql_query($qry);

 
 //changed current_id value finding method.
 $current_id = mysql_query("select uid from users ORDER BY uid DESC LIMIT 1"); //last insert id      

 
   if(!empty($current_id)) {
    
    $actual_link = "http://localhost/angular/php/"."activate.php?uid=" . $current_id;
    
    $EmailTo = $uemail;
    $Subject = "User Registration Activation Email";
    $Content = "Click this link to activate your account. <a href='" . $actual_link . "'>" . $actual_link . "</a>";
    $MailHeaders = "From: Admin\r\n";
    
    if(mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Content, $MailHeaders) ) {
     
           $arr = array('msg' => "You have registered and the activation mail is sent to your email. Click the activation link to activate you account.", 'error' => '');
                    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
                    print_r($jsn);
     
      }
    } 
 
}


else
{
     $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'User Already exists with same email');
    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
    print_r($jsn);
}
?>
```